# How to change the class of an element based on the class of another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a list of navigation items where when one is clicked it's status becomes active

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('li').click(function() {
        $('li').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');     
    });
});
```

I have a container div with multiple hidden divs inside and based on the order of the li that is active I want to be able to show the hidden div that is the same order as the li.

```
<div class="col-md-9">
    <div id="item1">
        <p>Section#1</p>
        <img src="image-plugin.jpg" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    <div id="item2">
        <p>Section#2</p>
        <img src="image-plugin.jpg" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    <div id="item3">
        <p>Section#3</p>
        <img src="image-plugin.jpg" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
</div>
```

So basically if the second li has the active class then I can have the second of the hidden divs be visible.

Ideally a solution that doesn't involve attaching id's to the li's would be best but I've been having trouble achieving this and would appreciate any help possible.

Comment: Did you know that jQuery objects containing multiple DOM elements can be dereferenced? `$($('li')[3])` will give you a jQuery object containing the third list item.

Comment: Thanks Sam! I didn't know that until know but i'll be sure to keep that in mind in the future!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look [**at this demo bootply**](http://www.bootply.com/lQLWOsSjek).
For this HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
  <ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item">Item 1</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Item 2</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Item 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="col-md-9">
    <div id="item1" class="showhide hidden">
        <p>Section#1</p>
        <img src="http://www.placehold.it/350x150" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    <div id="item2" class="showhide hidden">
        <p>Section#2</p>
        <img src="http://www.placehold.it/350x150" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    <div id="item3" class="showhide hidden">
        <p>Section#3</p>
        <img src="http://www.placehold.it/350x150" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
</div>
```

This JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('li').click(function() {
        $('li').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');    

      var index = $(this).index();
      $('.showhide').addClass('hidden').eq(index).removeClass('hidden');

    });
});
```

Comment: thank you so much for this! That did the trick perfectly. I never knew about that index capability, learned something knew :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `index()` method and following logic regarding click event:

```
$(document).on("click", "li:not(.active)", function () {
    $('li.active').add(this).toggleClass('active');
    $('div[id^=item]').hide().eq($(this).index()).show();
});
```

### -jsFiddle-

Answer (score 0):

You can use [index()](https://api.jquery.com/index/) which will return `order number - 1` of matched elements.
So you can write in next way:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('li').click(function() {
        $('li').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');    
        var thisIndex = $(this).index();
        $('.col-md-9 .div').eq(thisIndex).show();
    });
});
```